# In ggplot2, geom_text() labels are misplaced below my data points (as pictured). How to overlay them onto points?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I'm using ggplot2 to create a simple dot plot of -1 to +1 correlation values using the following R code:

```
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = exit)) + 
      geom_point(aes(y= row.names(dataframe))) + 
      geom_text(aes(y=exit, label=samplesize))
```

The y-axis has text labels, and I believe those text labels may be the reason that my geom_text() data point labels are squished down into the bottom of the plot as pictured here:

[image]

How can I change my plotting so that the data point labels appear on the dots themselves?

Comment: the x-variable is `exit` in the `geom_point` but it is also the y-var in `geom_text` ... this doesnt seem right. Does this help .. `ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = exit, y= row.names(dataframe), label=samplesize))) + 
      geom_point() +  geom_text()`

Comment: Or how about, `geom_text(size = 7, label=samplesize)` instead of using `aes()`? I believe you can change the coordinates of the texts as well.

Comment: @small_data88; i dont think your suggestion will work. `samplesize` does not exists outside of the `dataframe`, so will need to be in `aes` to be found, and also you have not defined a `y` position for the `geom_text` (and OP did not define it at the top level plot call)

Comment: Okay, then do `geom_text(size = 7, label=dataframe$samplesize)` You don't need the y value, the labels will just be on top of each data point(which is what I think she wants). If you specify a y-value, then the labels will all be on one line at that coordinate.

Comment: A y variable needs to be passed to `geom_text` one way or another, but if your code is added to the OP's this will not happen. A y variable of row.names(dataframe) in the top level plot, or within the geom_text will both work

Comment: Strange, I was able to do it without a y value argument in `geom_text()`. The labels all appear above each data point.

Comment: @small_data88 specifying the labels outside of `aes()` using `$` will work in simple cases, but will fail in more complex cases (e.g., if there are facets). Good practice is to put constants like `size = 7` outside of `aes()`, and references to data columns inside `aes()` with no `$`.

Comment: @Gregor that is good to keep in mind, thanks for the heads up. It doesn't look like the OP's plot has any facets and the data points would just be the correlations, so I would think it would be fine here.

Comment: @small_data88 Yes, but it's forming a bad habit when the good habit is just as easy---and it would be confusing to future people with a faceted graph trying to use this as a resource.

Comment: @Gregor The author uses it in the documentation without any arguments and the `mapping` parameter is set to null. It's only needed if you are overriding the plot's default mapping, which you are not. You are just adding a labels layer to the plot.

Comment: @Gregor It looks like using `aes()` is good in situations where it calls for you to have the data mapped to the lowest level of the plot(e.g. at each data point object); for example, if you have three groups of data in one plot and want to color code each one. If you just need to add undynamic properties that are applied to every point equally(making all points blue or adding labels), then I don't think it is imperative to call aes. Plus, I noticed that it adds the legend by default this way, which can look clunky at times.

Comment: @small_data88, yes! `aes()` is for *aesthetic mapping* from data to graphic elements, so you should use it whenever you're referencing your data. When you're setting constants, not referencing your data (like my `size = 7` example or your `color = 'blue'` example) then it should be outside of `aes()`. If you wanted to label every point `"point"`, put it outside of `aes()`, but if your labels *depend on the data*, they should go inside `aes()`. This will always work, whereas referencing the data frame outside of `aes()` will not work with facets or with certain `stat_*` functions.

Comment: I buy that, its more robust. I changed my `geom_text()` to utilize `aes()`. Thanks for pointing this out to me. I haven't had to use ggplot that much(I use highcharts), but this was a great learning experience.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. Working great now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simply that you switched the `y` variables:

```
# your code
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = exit)) + 
      geom_point(aes(y = row.names(dataframe))) +  # here y is the row names
      geom_text(aes(y =exit, label = samplesize))  # here y is the exit column
```

Since you want the same y-values for both you can define this in the initial `ggplot()` call and not worry about repeating it later

```
# working version
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = exit, y = row.names(dataframe))) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_text(aes(label = samplesize))
```

Using row names is a little fragile, it's a little safer and more robust to actually create a data column with what you want for y values:

```
# nicer code
dataframe$y = row.names(dataframe)
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = exit, y = y)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_text(aes(label = samplesize))
```

Having done this, you probably don't want the labels right on top of the points, maybe a little offset would be better:

```
# best of all?
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = exit, y = y)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_text(aes(x = exit + .05, label = samplesize), vjust = 0)
```

In the last case, you'll have to play with the adjustment to the `x` aesthetic, what looks right will depend on the dimensions of your final plot

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you would like to have the samplesize appear above each data point in the plot. Here is a sample plot with a sample data frame that does this:
EDIT: Per note by Gregor, changed the `geom_text()` call to utilize `aes()` when referencing the data. Thanks for the heads up!

```
top10_rank<-
      String Number
4       h      0
1       a      1
11      w      1
3       z      3
7       z      3
2       b      4
8       q      5
6       k      6
9       r      9
5       x     10
10      l     11

x<-ggplot(data=top10_rank, aes(x = Number, 
y = String)) + geom_point(size=3) +  scale_y_discrete(limits=top10_rank$String)

x + geom_text(data=top10_rank, size=5, color = 'blue', 
aes(x = Number,label = Number), hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

[image: Plot of Data with labels]

Not sure if this is what you wanted though.